# Derivatives problem

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given the equation $f(x)=\frac{2x+4}{\sqrt{x}}$, evaluate $f(0.5)$ and $f'(0.5)$.
I am having a problem understanding the problem. The first part is straight forward, but it's the second part I'm having problems with. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you learned how to derivate polynomials, square roots and ratios use them to find $f'(x)$ and plug in $.5$.

Otherwise
$$f'(0.5) =\lim_{x \to 0.5} \frac{f(x)-f(0.5)}{x-0.5}$$
and calculate the limit.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can't beleive how blind i was not to see that.

Answer (score 1):

So, $f=(2x+4)/\sqrt{x}$ implies $f'(x)=x^{-1/2}-2x^{-3/2}$.

Now just plug in $x=0.5$ and you'll have it!